# Git pull deleted local files

Tags: git, gitlab

On my project, before pushing to the remote branch I just run the git pull command, and it just deleted all the (new) local files that weren't in the branch. And, I didn't get a backup, if the files are deleted it should be somewhere on my computer, right?

Does anyone has faced with a similar issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you commit the changes locally @Nathan Harold

Comment: @NanduRaj Yes, I did.

Comment: revert back to previous commit and see if you are able to see the file. if git ls-files --deleted shows the deleted files than you can restore using git checkout filename.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `git reflog` to show a history of your actions in this repo. You should see something like this:

```
bb3139b... HEAD@{0}: pull : Fast forward
622f05a HEAD@{1}: commit: here i'm committing new local files
```

Basically you want to find the last commit you made before you lost your files. You want commit `622f05a`, so use this:

```
git reset 622f
```

This will "undo" your pull, but you can just `git pull` again whenever you want to to get those remote updates back.

Comment: Wow, that shows the missing files, although that didn't revert the files, should I run another command after git reset @symlink

Comment: @NathanHarold when you run `git status`, are the files in your files "Changes to be committed", "Changes not staged for commit", or "Untracked files"?

Comment: It's giving the following:
`
Your branch and 'origin/development' have diverged,
and have 7 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
`

Comment: @NathanHarold are the files that were missing committed? If not, you need to commit them and then `git pull` and resolve any merge conflicts. If so, just `git pull` and resolve the merge conflicts.

Comment: I didn't want to mass up something else, so I just used 'git restore' for each of the files deleted. It's all good now, and I don't know what to say, you saved me 1 week of work!!! Thank you so much!

Comment: @NathanHarold glad to hear it!

Answer (score 2):

Since you have committed your changes in local git, you can get rid of all changes and move to the current/previous commit(which you prefer).

This will reset everything to your current commit (getting rid of all changes, staged or otherwise):

```
git reset HEAD --hard
```

This will reset everything to the previous commit (also getting rid of all changes, staged or otherwise):

```
git reset HEAD^ --hard
```

the ^ next to HEAD means one commit before HEAD, HEAD being where you are currently. You can go two commits back by using ^^, or three with ^^^. Additionally, you can use a tilde to specify the number of commits: ~3 for three commits back.

```
git reset HEAD~3 --hard
```

Also, keep in mind that the --hard option means that these commands will throw away any changes you have that are not stashed.

Comment: Did this help? @Nathan Harold

Comment: Thank you, @NanduRaj , but this didn't solve my problem. Do you have another idea to find the files locally?

Comment: I did a silly thing before posting the question. I have deleted the folder after pulling the changes (without sawing it changed all the local files), and pull the branch from scratch. So, when I run the command you shared, it just reverts back to the original stage (which is kinda an empty folder).

Comment: Oh then I am not sure I can help @NathanHarold. Please post the answer if you found a work around.

Comment: Did you delete it permanently or can you restore it from trash? If yes, try that.